# Jupyter Notebook: cmd error access denied (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am not the administrator of my machine. I installed the jupyter as follows

```
pip -m install jupyter
```

The problem I have now is that when I try to log up a session on Windows 10 on cmd with

```
jupyter notebook
```

from the console, I have the error `access denied` and i can't use jupyter.[image]

Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In VSCODE or in the terminal run the following script:

```
import sys

!{sys.executable} -m pip install jupyter
```

Comment: That `!` syntax isn't valid Python (and `import sys` isn't valid bash / PowerShell /etc.). Do you mean to run this from a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Try there or you can create a new py file in vscode, and if you have the extension to run python scripts in the terminal I think it will work. Or install anaconda, for that doesn't need admin privileges, open spyder and run that script

Comment: Most of those options are some form of Python. Again, that `!` syntax is not valid Python. And if you mean to run this in a notebook, doesn't that mean Jupyter is already installed?